# Initial load and when I change value of input doesn't show message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, frontend

everyone, I have some problem with fetching data and displaying message on initial loading as well as when I change some of the input filed value. The idea here is to display specific message in two cases after doing some calculation.

```
const potrosnja = document.getElementById('potrosnja');
const nagib = document.getElementById('nagib');
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
const poruka = document.getElementById('poruka');
let str = document.querySelector('input[name="strane-sveta"]:checked').value;

let godisnjaPotrosnja = parseInt(potrosnja.value);
let nagibKrovaInput = nagib.value;

//On button submit it fetches data and calculate the value needed for yearly consumption of energy 

//fetching data

async function dataFetch(){
    let response = await fetch('./csvjson.json')
    let data = await response.json();
    data.map(strana => {
        strana.strana.map((item, i) => {
            try {
                if(item == str && nagibKrovaInput == strana.nagib) {
                    let result = Math.ceil(godisnjaPotrosnja / strana.vrednost[i]);
                    console.log("try works")
                    poruka.innerHTML = `You need <span class="kw">${result}</span>`
                }
             }
             catch(err) {
                poruka.innerHTML = `Please fill required fields.`
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    })
}

//event listeners

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {    
    dataFetch()
    console.log('clicked')
    input.forEach(input => {
        if(input.value == ''){
            input.classList.add("active");
        }
    })
})
```

I can see that the problem is inside try function, it like condition isn't treated on initial load, and I have to reload page so it would work. Can someone help me understanding what is the problem?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If the fetch works, then no need to add the fetch to the snippet - an example object is enough

Comment: I believe that problem is something with if statement, but cant understand why doesn't it work on initial load, and works normal on reload of the page...

Comment: he said `I can see that the problem is inside try function` and it happens to be inside that function. Anyway it's hard to understand but for sure those dom querying on top should be after document ready so this whole block, plus you may add await in front of the dataFetch call but I'm not sure if the next statements are supposed to wait. Anyway that's not going to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution... First thing I have to do Is to check if nagibKrovaInput == strana.nagib, after I get true, I compared does the indexOf item is equal as str and after I get true, it will display something. I also changed on click on the button to send values to data function as an arguments and It solved the problem. Tnx for help.